# How to create Swift protocol, that can be used in Array?

Tags: swift, protocols

I have 2 different classes (NSObject, RealmObject) that should conform to one common protocol Listening.

```
protocol Listening: class {
  var filter: String? { get }
}
```

Then I have this parent class that has array `var allListeningObjects: [Listening]` which should hold all objects that conform to this protocol. But before I can run it, I get this error: Type 'Listening' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Im open to any advice that can make this work.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the error you are getting - it would seem you are attempting to you use your `Listening` protocol as a the type of a key in a dictionary or as the type of element in a set - and not as the type of the elements in an array. Double check the type definition of the `allListeningObjects` and ensure it is actually an array, not a set or dictionary.

If you are intending to use your `Listening` protocol in this context - [Apple has some nice documentation on how to implement](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/hashable) `Hashable`

Comment: …or as a member of a `Set`.

Comment: thanks @PauloMattos - updated answer to include this possibility as well

Comment: i actually have a set instead of array. I just change it to array for publishing here on SO. I thought that all collection types have issue with protocols. var allListeningObjects: Set<Listening>.   I will take a look at the link you gave me.